# Cloudfront for serving static S3 content - use S3Origin or CustomOrigin?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm setting up a CloudFront distribution to host a static single-page webapp on S3. At first, I used a custom origin towards my bucket, but after deploying my CloudFormation template, going to the distribution URL just gave a 403 error. After going into the AWS console and changing type to S3, it works.
I want to understand the difference between these two types of origins.

In the CloudFormation reference for CloudFront, there's [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-origin.html#cfn-cloudfront-distribution-origin-customoriginconfig):

> Use this type to specify an origin that is not an Amazon S3 bucket, with one exception. If the Amazon S3 bucket is configured with static website hosting, use this type. If the Amazon S3 bucket is not configured with static website hosting, use the S3OriginConfig type instead.

What is the difference in practice between setting up a CF distribution using an *S3 origin* towards a bucket *without* static hosting enabled, and a CF distribution using a *custom origin* towards a bucket *with* static hosting enabled? Is there a difference in performance, cost, flexibility, ...?